# How i can get full screen in Vbox , facing error

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

i have tried it to fix by going    devices-->insert guest additions..
But facing this error

```
Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine Ubuntu.
Would you like to try to force insertion of this disk?
Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have Ubuntu as your Guest Operating System.

Open a Terminal in Ubuntu and enter the following -

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

This package will install the guest additions.